# Laravel 8 problem with @include and variables from controller

Tags: php, laravel

When I try include home page from Pages/home, variables from controller won't passing and I have this error

> $data_news is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade
> template. Replace {{ $data_news }} with {{ $data_news ?? '' }}

, but when I return view home page I see all data

**Controller**

```
public function pages()
{
    $data_news = DB::table('post')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

    return view('Pages.home', compact('data_news'));
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/home', 'NewsController@pages', function () {
    return view('Pages/home');
});
```

**Main file where home page is included**

```
<body>
    @include('Pages/home')
```

Comment: Why you add `@include` in view ? if you want pass data to other blade : `@include('Pages/home' , ['data_news' => $data_news])`  and change route to `Route::get('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\NewsController::class, 'pages'])`

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should not define closure function when you're pointing to a controller in your route. Change that like below:

```
Route::get('/home', 'NewsController@pages');
```

**Note for laravel 8:** You should put the complete namespace of your controller class in your routes, as it is not defined in the `RouteServiceProvider` as it used to be in laravel below version 8.

```
Route::get('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\NewsController::class, 'pages']);
```

### Passing a parameter directly to a view

You can benefit from view composer as it is documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers):

```
public function pages()
{
    $data_news = DB::table('post')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

    \View::composer('Pages.home',function (\Illuminate\View\View $view) use($data_news) {
        $view->with('data_news', $data_news);
    });

    return view('Pages.home', compact('data_news'));
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have any specific error?

Comment: Yes, see up $data_news is variable from controller and when I include home page to main page file I have Error Exception $data_news is undefined

Comment: I put full namespace.
`<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\NewsController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('Templates/weball');
});
Route::get('/home', 'NewsController@pages');`

Comment: I added view composer, Also, change `@include('Pages/home')` to `@include('Pages.home')`

Comment: Result it's the same, Now I try use @yield but not working for me, I getting site without any data